# "Linking" to different versions of automake/autoconf tools

Tags: autoconf, automake

I am currently working on a machine to which I do not have sudo privileges.  I am trying to build a library which requires Autoconf and Automake versions higher than the currently installed versions.  I successfully installed autoconf in my home directory.  However, the version of automake I am installing ALSO requires an autoconf version higher than the currently installed version.

**My question:**

If possible, how do you tell configure files where to find autoconf/automake if they are installed in non-default locations?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't really need to tell them anything.  Just put the path to the overriding autoconf/automake before the system autoconf/automake path in `PATH` and it should work.